# TypeScript: error when updating common property in union type

Tags: typescript, generics

I have the following union type.

```
type Common = { commonProp: string };
type MyFoo = Common & { foo: number };
type MyBar = Common & { bar: number };
type MyUnion = { tag: 'MyFoo'; value: MyFoo } | { tag: 'MyBar'; value: MyBar };
declare const myUnion: MyUnion;
```

If I write a function to update the property that is common to all union members (`commonProp`), I get an error:

```
// Error
/*
Type '{ value: { commonProp: string; foo: number; } | { commonProp: string; bar: number; }; tag: "MyFoo"; } | { value: { commonProp: string; foo: number; } | { commonProp: string; bar: number; }; tag: "MyBar"; }' is not assignable to type 'MyUnion'.
    Type '{ value: { commonProp: string; foo: number; } | { commonProp: string; bar: number; }; tag: "MyFoo"; }' is not assignable to type 'MyUnion'.
        Type '{ value: { commonProp: string; foo: number; } | { commonProp: string; bar: number; }; tag: "MyFoo"; }' is not assignable to type '{ tag: "MyFoo"; value: MyFoo; }'.
            Types of property 'value' are incompatible.
                Type '{ commonProp: string; foo: number; } | { commonProp: string; bar: number; }' is not assignable to type 'MyFoo'.
                    Type '{ commonProp: string; bar: number; }' is not assignable to type 'MyFoo'.
                    Property 'foo' is missing in type '{ commonProp: string; bar: number; }' but required in type '{ foo: number; }'.ts(2322)
*/
const updateDescription = (t: MyUnion): MyUnion => ({
    ...t,
    value: {
        ...t.value,
        commonProp: 'foo',
    },
});
```

Why does this error?

I seem to be able to workaround around this by making the function generic (constrained to the union), but I don't understand why this would work when the previous non-generic function does not.

```
// No error
const updateCommonProp = <T extends MyUnion>(t: T): T => ({
    ...t,
    value: {
        ...t.value,
        commonProp: 'foo',
    },
});
```

Why does the generic function work when the non-generic function does not?

Comment: Actually I am surprised the generic version works.. I would expect that to fail too .. I think it's because spread generates intersections for generic type parameters ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think we can get the best insight into how the compiler reasons here if we remove the return type annotations and see what the compiler thinks about the return types.

```
// If no return type, updateDescription is inferred to:
const updateDescription: (t: MyUnion) => {
    value: {
        commonProp: string;
        foo: number;
    } | {
        commonProp: string;
        bar: number;
    };
    tag: "MyFoo";
} | {
    value: {
        commonProp: string;
        foo: number;
    } | {
        commonProp: string;
        bar: number;
    };
    tag: "MyBar";
}
```

Typescript does not track relations between variables or properties in any way. So when you spread `t` the result is something with the same type as `t`, then you add a `value` property, which will override the `value` property of `t`. `t` being the `MyUnion` union, it will override `value` in each member of the union.

But here comes the problem. The `value` you are adding contains a spread of `t.value`. But that will itself be a union of all possible values in `MyUnion` (`MyUnion['value']`). The result is that now each member of the original union is paired with a union of all possible values making it unassignable to the original union. ‍♂️‍♂️

For generics the story is very different. The compiler can't just replace the `value` property in the union because `T` is not known inside the function. It actually used to be an error to use generic types in spread operations until 3.2 ([PR](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/28234)). Since 3.2 the behavior was changed to use intersection types which at first glance should be equivalent. So lets see that the compiler thinks the return type of the generic version is:

```
// If no return type ts infers for updateCommonProp:
const updateCommonProp: <T extends MyUnion>(t: T) => T & {
    value: {
        commonProp: string;
        foo: number;
    } | {
        commonProp: string;
        bar: number;
    };
}
```

We see the that the `value` property we added generates the same union as before. However this is assignable to `T` because, by definition, an intersection type is assignable to any of its constituents. So it does not matter that if we were to actually do a merge of the intersection the result would not be assignable all that matters is that we are assigning to one member of the intersection.

Another workaround is to use this intersection assignment rule to our advantage without the generic function. We could just use `Object.assign` which return an intersection of arguments, without doing the type surgery spread does:

```
const updateDescription = (t: MyUnion): MyUnion => Object.assign({}, t, {
    value: {
        ...t.value,
        commonProp2: 'foo',
    },
});
```

In all fairness the non-generic version is the more type safe version. Since ts does not track relations between variables it can't tell that what you are doing is not this:

```
const updateDescription = (t: MyUnion, tOther: MyUnion) => ({
    ...t,
    value: {
        ...tOther.value,
        commonProp2: 'foo',
    },
});
```

From a types perspective the single parameter version is the same as this two parameter version, but this one is obviously not type safe since the `type` field of the two parameters does not have to coincide.